# how to get redux store data of products which is passed to add from add to cart page

Tags: react-native

how to use redux for ecom like application where we can add products and it increases the count now here how to get the store data of which the id we stored to increase the count i am able to store the data but while getting i am getting an error ?

```
  Class {
"_dispatchInstances": null,
"_dispatchListeners": null,
"_targetInst": FiberNode {
  "tag": 5,
  "key": null,
  "type": "RCTView",
},
"bubbles": undefined,
"cancelable": undefined,
"currentTarget": null,
"defaultPrevented": undefined,
"dispatchConfig": Object {
  "dependencies": Array [],
  "registrationName": "onResponderGrant",
},
"eventPhase": undefined,
"isDefaultPrevented": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
"isPersistent": [Function functionThatReturnsTrue],
"isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
"isTrusted": undefined,
"nativeEvent": Object {
  "changedTouches": Array [
    [Circular],
  ],
  "identifier": 0,
  "locationX": 2.53955078125,
  "locationY": 17.95975112915039,
  "pageX": 331.53955078125,
  "pageY": 57.95975112915039,
  "target": 2595,
  "timestamp": 42790002,
  "touches": Array [
    [Circular],
  ],
},
"target": 2595,
"timeStamp": 1582794322382,
"touchHistory": Object {
  "indexOfSingleActiveTouch": 0,
  "mostRecentTimeStamp": 42790167,
  "numberActiveTouches": 0,
  "touchBank": Array [
    Object {
      "currentPageX": 331.53955078125,
      "currentPageY": 57.95975112915039,
      "currentTimeStamp": 42790167,
      "previousPageX": 331.53955078125,
      "previousPageY": 57.95975112915039,
      "previousTimeStamp": 42790002,
      "startPageX": 331.53955078125,
      "startPageY": 57.95975112915039,
      "startTimeStamp": 42790002,
      "touchActive": false,
    },
  ],
},
"type": undefined,
```

},
]

some thing like this in my console

this is my store component for redux

```
  import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import cartItems from '../reducers/cartItems'

export default store = createStore(cartItems);
```

and this is the reducers component '

```
 const cartItems = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
            return [...state, action.payload]
        case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
            return state.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id)
    }

    return state
}

export default cartItems
```

now to get the products in my cart component ?

and this is the compoent where storing the data

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addItemToCart: (product) => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TO_CART', payload: product })

    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ContentPage)
```

this is my cart component ?

```
const CartComponent = props => {
  props.cartItems // will be your cart items

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        cartItems: state
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        removeItem: (product) => dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_FROM_CART', payload: product })
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Yourcart);
```

Answer (score 1):

to access a data from the redux store, you need to provide the first parameter to the connect function, which you are not doing

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ContentPage)
```

the first parameter should be like this

```
const mapStateToProps = reduxStore => {
 return {
  cartItems: reduxStore
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps , mapDispatchToProps)(ContentPage)
```

Comment: so i should use this function in reducers component?

Comment: const CartComponent = props => {
  props.cartItems // will be your cart items

}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addItemToCart: (product) => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TO_CART', payload: product })

    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ContentPage)

Comment: you mean as like this?

Comment: i understood that i have to make an state function and pass it as props so the card item would be in statetoprops to redux store but how shuld i call

Comment: what to you mean

Comment: how do i show the products which we store in the redux should i call directly props.cartitems

Comment: but how i should define it or it will throw props not found error ?

Comment: there will be some redux mthod to make an fucntion to call?

Comment: props.cartItems will be equal to the key you passed in the mapStateToProps function